# Can not find tools.jar under java home when using arthas in openjdk

Tags: java

I am using arthas 3.3.6 in kubernetes docker container with openjdk8, when I start arthas, it shows:

```
/opt/arthas # java -jar arthas-boot.jar 1
[INFO] arthas-boot version: 3.3.6
[INFO] arthas home: /opt/arthas
[INFO] Try to attach process 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find tools.jar under java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre, please try to start arthas-boot with full path java. Such as /opt/jdk/bin/java -jar arthas-boot.jar
        at com.taobao.arthas.boot.ProcessUtils.findJavaHome(ProcessUtils.java:222)
        at com.taobao.arthas.boot.ProcessUtils.startArthasCore(ProcessUtils.java:233)
        at com.taobao.arthas.boot.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:515)
```

then I download the oracle JDK and throw this error:

```
  /opt/arthas # /opt/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java -jar arthas-boot.jar
sh: /opt/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java: not found
```

I am searching from internet and tell me the OracleJDK C lib is imcompatible with alpine.someone copy the tools.jar into docker container still not fix this problem. so what should I do to make arthas works?

Comment: I'm guessing, but it sound like you have used a docker container with an OpenJDK JRE-only installation in it.

Comment: But if you can run `javac`, then the problem could be that arthas needs you to set JAVA_HOME correctly.

Comment: I  still not understand what should I do to make it work.@StephenC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about this question，Maybe there are two solutions besides switching the base image of docker file：

- The JVM of the target process is the JRE of openjdk, not JDK. There is no tools.jar. You can manually specify the path of tools.jar when starting Arthas

  `java -jar arthas-boot.jar -Dtools.jar=./tools.jar`
- Reinstall JDK and set JAVA_HOME is new with tools JDK directory of jar.
- Change the base image to openjdk:8. just like your solution.

Comment: However, according to the docker operation, the third solution is the most reasonable，thanks！

Answer (score 0):

change the base image to `openjdk:8`.

```
FROM openjdk:8
```

works.